# Executing JS function from AJAX response having HTML + JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using AJAX for the first time to avoid page refresh on form submit. It works perfectly, data is received in HTML form and placed inside the desired `div`, the only thing not working is one of the JS function which I am using to draw a pie chart on the page.

I already Googled about my problem but found some solutions in which the response was only `JS` but in my case, response contains HTML including `<script>` tags which doesn't seem to work? I re-created my problem below, have a look :

index.php:

```
<p>Name :</p>
<input type="text" id="main-id">
<input type="submit" id="grab" value="Grab!">

<div id="my-data"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/global.js"> </script>
<script src="js/pie.js"></script>
```

global.js:

```
$('#grab').on('click', function() {
    var main-id = $('#main-id').val();
    $.post('data.php', { main-id: main-id }, function(data) {
        $('#my-data').html(data);
    },'html');  
});
```

`var data` gets all the echo's from `data.php` including the script tags.

Snippet from my code which is causing me trouble:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#pieChart").drawPieChart([{
            title: "Monday",
            value: 12,
            color: "#808080>"
        }, {
            title: "Tuesday",
            value: 28,
            color: "#000000"
        }, {
            title: "Wednesday",
            value: 32,
            color: "#FF0000"
        }, {
            title: "Thursday",
            value: 8,
            color: "#800000"
        }, {
            title: "Friday",
            value: 20,
            color: "#7133FF"
        }]);
    });
</script>

<div id="pieChart" class="chart"> </div>
```

The JS function `.drawPieChart` when called fills the `#pieChart div` with a piechart, but in my case its placed as raw code inside the page, `#pieChart div` remains blank.

How can I call `.drawPieChart` after its placed inside the page?

**UPDATE :**

Pie Chart CSS:

```
    /*   Pie chart   */

.chart {
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  float:left;

}
.pieTip {
   position: absolute;
   display:none;
  z-index: 9;
  float: left;
  min-width: 30px;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 5px 18px 6px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.97);
  color: #444;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.3;
  letter-spacing: .06em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  -webkit-transform: all .3s;
     -moz-transform: all .3s;
      -ms-transform: all .3s;
       -o-transform: all .3s;
          transform: all .3s;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.pieTip:after {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      bottom: -6px;
      display:none;
      content: "";
      height: 0;
      margin: 0 0 0 -6px;
      border-right: 5px solid transparent;
      border-left: 5px solid transparent;
      border-top: 6px solid rgba(255,255,255,.95);
      line-height: 0;
}
.chart path { cursor: pointer; }
```

Comment: I don't see how your AJAX call relates to the pie chart library?

Comment: what js library is `.drawPieChart` included?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to call the above written `JS function`, I cannot post the whole pie chart library code here. See if the script part and the html part (written above) is present in a HTML file and is loaded, it will create a  piechart inside the `#pieChart` div. Thats how this function works. But here in my case it placed as raw code inside the HTML page. `#pieChart` remains empty which means `<script>` is not running.

Comment: why don't you try putting it on a function and execute it on success.

Comment: @JericCruz This is the exact library I'm using : https://codepen.io/githiro/pen/xABCi

Comment: @Mike I'm total beginner in this AJAX thing, can you post some example code. Please.

Comment: did you included the script for this library?

Comment: Yes, its already included in the page, I mean not via this AJAX response, but my main page where the response is collected in HTML form already has a reference to the script of the library.

Comment: One question, I didn't see jquery.drawPieChart.js did you included? as @JericCruz says

Comment: Is "data" the piechart data on your page?

Comment: @Dranes `data` is the code which you see below `Snippet from my code..` line + some more `divs`

Comment: @Mike I updated my code, included `pie.js` script in `index.php`

Comment: Ok,  on your data code, put the HTML tags before the javascript or use $(document).ready

Comment: @Dranes Isn't  `$()`  shorthand for `$( document ).ready()` ? I already have my JS before `$()` ?

Comment: no, its not! $() indicates that is jQuery

Comment: @Dranes tried it, didn't work. Saw my console, it says `$(...).drawPieChart is not a function` but if I just refresh the page with same code, it works?

Comment: kindly include the CSS too.

Comment: Updated, with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting that error is that "SVG Pie chart with tooltip and hover effects" library is not included.

Kindly include JS and CSS files(from `codepen.io/githiro/pen/xABCi`) in your master/layout view. You can save it on a notepad as ".js" and ".css" then include it to your project.